# file crawler OSError

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

I want this to recursively call the next file, listed in a manually inputted file. It is the first word listed in the file.

The current error messege is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'file1.txt\n'.
```

This is my current code:

```
import os
def crawl(fname):
infile = open(fname, 'r')
if os.stat(fname)[6]==0:
    return "Visiting {}".format(fname)
    infile.close()
else:
    print ("Visiting {}".format(fname))
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    nextfile = lines[0].strip()
    for line in lines:
        crawl(nextfile)
```

Comment: How do you call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
def crawl(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as infile:
        print("Visiting {}".format(fname))
        if os.stat(fname).st_size:
            lines = infile.read().splitlines()
            for line in lines:
                crawl(line)
```

Comment: thanks, but another question, I want to make sure my "if" statement is working. os.stat(fname)[6]==0 will check if the file is empty correct?

Comment: Yes, this check is absolutely correct. However `os.stat(fname).st_size` is more clear.

Comment: There is a problem with this code still, it gets stuck on file1.txt. It reads file3.txt, but does not output:    "Visiting file3.txt"    It outputs:    "Visiting file1.txt"    Then it closes.

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to the formatting for this site.

Comment: lets say I wanted the code to try the second file listed. lines[1]. if lines[0]'s file was empty.

Comment: Updated my code in order to crawl all lines. Do you want to try lines[1] if line[0] is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're getting a newline at the end of the filename you are reading from the first file. You can easily fix it, by using the `strip` method to remove the newline:

```
nextfile = lines[0].strip()
```

Comment: I tried that, but I found it now has a different problem. It runs the recursion once, then stops.

Comment: @JasonSchayer probably my answer helps with this issue.